# Put javascript blob variable in src of audio

Tags: javascript, audio, controls, blob, src

In my javascript code I create a url from my audio blob

```
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I then have an audio controller. How do I put the blobUrl variable into the src = ?

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src= blobUrl type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `source` element and set its `src` property.

Lets get the element using the basic js DOM API.

```
var srcElement = document.getElementsByTagName("source")[0]; // Assuming there's only one
```

Now lets set the `src` property using

`srcElement.src = blobUrl;` or `srcElement.setAttribute("src", blobUrl);` or jquery's `element.attr()` method if you get the element using a jquery selector.